# Travis CI with AWS 'assume role'

Tags: amazon-web-services, travis-ci, assume-role, sts

Our AWS accounts are set up so that users login to one account, and then 'assume role' to different accounts to access various services.

We have TravisCI setup so that it runs an integration test against a test account, and then uploads a build artifact into S3.

Currently this is done using a single set of IAM user credentials with the user in the test account. I would like to move the user into a different account, and then have TravisCI assume the correct role in the test account to run the tests, and then assume a different role in another account to upload the build artifact. I do not want to add users to the accounts themselves.

I cannot see this functionality built in to the [S3 deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/s3/) and have not had any luck finding anyone else trying to do this.

I think that this may be possible by dynamically populating environment variables during a setup phase, and then passing the variable on to later stages, but I cannot work out if this is possible.

Does anyone have assume role working with TravisCI?

Comment: While this is a suitable strategy, it should be noted that S3 does cross-account permissions, so you can upload to S3 in account A with access credentials for account B.

Comment: Yeah, it could work with a cross-account bucket policy, but I still have the issue of the integration tests. Also, we're looking to move into docker containers with ECR which has an even more complex authentication process.